# Dense.get_weights() vs Dense.weights

Tags: python, tensorflow

Why get_weights() returns different values for weights compared to actual weights? I think after initialization both methods should show the same weights.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

sess = tf.Session()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3])

linear_model = tf.layers.Dense(units=1,use_bias=False,activation=None)
y = linear_model(x)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

print(linear_model.get_weights())
print(sess.run(linear_model.weights))
print('------------------')
print(sess.run(y, {x: [[1, 1, 1]]}))
```

Output

```
[array([[-0.26290017],
    [ 0.11782396],
    [ 0.51118207]], dtype=float32)]
[array([[-0.12011003],
    [ 0.13160932],
    [ 1.1303514 ]], dtype=float32)]
------------------
[[1.1418507]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code there are actually two `tf.Session()` instances; the fix is to enclose the use of your `sess` in a `with` clause like this:

```
# Define your graph.

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # All calls to tf.run() or linear_model.get_weights() go in this clause.
```

Why are there two sessions?

The first is your own `sess` object, which is not very mysterious.

The second is implicitly created by your call to `get_weights()`, which will create a new session instance for you if TensorFlow's default session is not set. Because you're using `sess` outside a `with` clause, you haven't set the default session, and `get_weights()` silently creates a new session for you. When you set up a `tf.Session()` in a `with` clause, it does set the default session in `tf`, and `get_weights()` will silently (and more helpfully) re-use your session object.

In case you're super-curious, the actual function that sneakily creates the other session for you is (in keras within tensorflow) [`keras.backend.get_session()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.10/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L412).